# How do I get inside Python http.client.HTTPResponse objects?

Tags: python, object, httpresponse

I've tried dir(), but the commands just return messages like this:

```
<bound method HTTPResponse.begin of <http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x00E9DEF0>>
```

which I'm afraid I don't know how to interpret.

Disclaimer: I haven't used Python much at all, so this may be a really stupid question. Please be gentle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods, just as functions, must be followed by parens (`()`), optionally containing arguments, in order to invoke them.

```
someobj.somemeth()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print the contents of A HTTPResponse object line by line like this

```
# Get the object from a url
url = 'https://www.example.com'
response_object = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

# Print the contents line by line 
for line in response_object:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

`HTTPResponse.read()` function can be used to get the body of the HTTPResponse. The function `HTTPresponse.read()` reads the `http.client.HTTPResponse` object and returns the response body.  More about it can be found in Python docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#httpresponse-objects

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(some_request)
body = response.read()
```

*Note:`urllib.request.urlopen(some_request)` returns HTTP response object*